# Is this the right approach to solve $\sin 4 \omega - \sin 6 \omega=0$ analytically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

$$\sin 4 \omega - \sin 6 \omega=0$$

What I did to solve this problem was to do a bit of algebraic work as shown below

$$\sin 4 \omega - \sin 6 \omega=0$$

$$2 \sin 2 \omega \cos 2 \omega - \left ( \sin 4 \omega \cos 2 \omega + \cos 4 \omega \sin 2 \omega \right )= 0$$

$$2 \sin 2 \omega \cos 2 \omega - \sin 4 \omega \cos 2 \omega - \cos 4 \omega \sin 2 \omega = 0$$

$$2 \sin 2 \omega \cos 2 \omega - 2 \sin 2 \omega \cos 2\omega \times \cos 2 \omega - \left ( \cos ^{2} 2 \omega - \sin ^{2} 2 \omega \right ) \sin 2 \omega = 0$$

$$2 \sin 2 \omega \cos 2 \omega - 2 \sin 2 \omega \cos 2\omega \times \cos 2 \omega - \left ( \cos ^{2} 2 \omega - \left (1-\cos ^{2} 2 \omega \right ) \right ) \sin 2 \omega = 0$$

$$2 \sin 2 \omega \cos 2 \omega - 2 \sin 2 \omega \cos ^{2} 2\omega - \left ( \cos ^{2} 2 \omega - 1+\cos ^{2} 2 \omega \right ) \sin 2 \omega = 0$$

$$2 \sin 2 \omega \cos 2 \omega - 2 \sin 2 \omega \cos ^{2} 2\omega - \left ( 2 \cos ^{2} 2 \omega - 1 \right ) \sin 2 \omega = 0$$

$$\sin 2 \omega  \left ( 2 \cos 2 \omega - 2 \cos ^{2} 2 \omega - 2 \cos^{2} 2 \omega +1 \right ) = 0$$

$$\sin 2 \omega  \left (- 4 \cos ^{2} 2 \omega + 2 \cos 2 \omega +1 \right ) = 0$$

$$- \sin 2 \omega  \left ( 4 \cos ^{2} 2 \omega - 2 \cos 2 \omega - 1 \right ) = 0$$

Then dividing both sides by $ -1 $:

$$\sin 2 \omega  \left ( 4 \cos ^{2} 2 \omega - 2 \cos 2 \omega - 1 \right ) = 0$$

Now here is where I'm in doubt:

Should I go on this route?

$\sin 2 \omega = 0$

Therefore: (in the interval of $[0, 2\pi ]$)

$2 \omega = 0$

$\omega = 0$

$2 \omega = \pi$

$\omega = \frac{\pi}{2}$

$2 \omega = 2 \pi$

$\omega = \pi$

$\omega = \left \{0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi \right \}$

Then in the other factor:

$$4 \cos ^{2} 2 \omega - 2 \cos 2 \omega - 1 = 0$$

$$\cos 2 \omega = \frac{-\left( -2 \right ) \pm \sqrt {(-2)^{2}-4(4)(-1)}}{2\times 4}$$

$$\cos 2 \omega = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt {20}}{8}=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt {5}}{4}$$

$$\cos 2 \omega = \frac{1 + \sqrt {5}}{4}$$

$$2 \omega = \cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 + \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )$$

$$\omega = \frac{\cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 + \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2}$$

Since this value is positive then the other choice in the interval $[0, 2\pi ]$ would be:

$$\omega = 2 \pi - \frac{\cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 + \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2} = \frac{4 \pi - \cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 + \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2}$$

Finally for the second solution of the quadratic equation:

$$\cos 2 \omega = \frac{1 - \sqrt {5}}{4}$$

Since this value is negative, the angle $\omega$ must be in the second quadrant and the third quadrant, therefore:

$$\omega = \frac{\cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 - \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2}$$

then the other solution in the interval $[0, 2\pi ]$ would be:

$$\omega = 2 \pi - \frac{\cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 - \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2} = \frac{4 \pi - \cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 - \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2}$$

Therefore the solution so far for these four would be:

$$\omega = \left \{ \frac{\cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 + \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2}, \frac{4 \pi - \cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 + \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2}, \frac{\cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 - \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2} , \frac{4 \pi - \cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 - \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2} \right \}$$

Then adding the other two which I obtained before would make $\omega$ this set:

$$\omega = \left \{ 0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi ,\frac{\cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 + \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2}, \frac{4 \pi - \cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 + \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2}, \frac{\cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 - \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2} , \frac{4 \pi - \cos^{-1} \left ( \frac{1 - \sqrt {5}}{4} \right )}{2} \right \}$$

But my question arises whether if the preceding set is the correct way to go:

I had doubts whether should I use

$$\sin 2 \omega = 0$$

$$\sin 2 \omega = \sqrt{1 - \cos 2 \omega} = 0$$

$$\sqrt{1 - \cos 2 \omega} = 0$$

$$1 - \cos 2 \omega = 0$$

$$\cos 2 \omega = 1$$

$$\omega = \frac{\cos^{-1} \left ( 1 \right )}{2}= 0 , \frac {2 \pi}{2}$$

$$\omega = 0, \pi$$

But here the "answer" $\frac{\pi}{2}$ seems missing. Did I miss something?. I'd hope somebody can help me whether to look if my procedure was appropriate for this case. The reason why I decided to change the sine function into cosine for solving the equation was because I was not sure if is allowed to equate to zero both factors if the functions are different or do they have to be the same?. But changing from one function to another I seem to miss one answer. Is my logic in the right path?

Comment: It might be a lot easier to use the formula $\sin A - \sin B = 2\cos\tfrac{A+B}{2}\sin \tfrac{A-B}{2}$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Actually I wanted to go on that route at the beginning but I didn't know where to go from both factors I mean $-2 \cos 5 \omega \sin \omega=0$, to equate both the cosine and sine to zero didn't seem right. Or could I be misunderstanding something.

Comment: But the only way for $2\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$ to equal $0$ is if either $\cos\alpha = 0$ or $\sin\beta = 0$ or both, so...

Comment: Generally speaking, you should always rejoice when you are able to write that a product equals $0$.

Comment: @giobrach Yes I knew about this, but in my attempt to verify from the method I wrote with that of prosthaphaeresis formula I couldn't get to the quadratic form neither reproduce the other results I obtained hence I am asking.

Comment: @Suzet Yes, but I wonder what are the caveats on that rule. I was warned in my book that one should not simplify expressions so easily because you can lose some solutions.

Comment: +1 for using the word "prosthaphaeresis".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We analyze the errors in your approach:**

Your procedure was fine until you attempted to solve the equation $\sin 2\omega = 0$.

In your first approach, you missed the solutions $\omega = \dfrac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi$.

In your second approach, 
\begin{align*}
\sin^2 2\omega + \cos^2 2\omega & = 1\\
\sin^2 2\omega & = 1 - \cos^2 2\omega\\
|\sin 2\omega| & = \sqrt{1 - \cos^{\color{red}{2}} 2\omega}\\
\sin 2\omega & = \color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{1 - \cos^{\color{red}{2}} 2\omega}\\
0 & = \color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{1 - \cos^{\color{red}{2}} 2\omega}\\
0 & = 1 - \cos^{\color{red}{2}} 2\omega\\
\cos^{\color{red}{2}} 2\omega & = 1\\
|\cos 2\omega| & = 1\\
\cos 2\omega & = \color{red}{\pm} 1
\end{align*}
which again yields the solutions 
$$\omega = 0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi$$
The value $\omega = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ clearly is an answer to the original equation since 
$$\sin 4\omega - \sin 6\omega = \sin\left(4 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \sin\left(6 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \sin(2\pi) - \sin(3\pi) = 0 - 0 = 0$$
Similarly, you can verify that $0$, $\pi$, $\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$, and $2\pi$ are solutions to the original equation by direct substitution.

In solving the equation 
$$4\cos^2 2\omega - 2\cos 2\omega + 1 = 0$$
you overlooked the fact that if $\omega \in [0, 2\pi]$, then $2\omega \in [0, 4\pi]$, so you missed four more solutions.

Since $\cos(-x) = \cos x$, $\cos 2\omega = \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4} \implies$ 
$$2\omega = \arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$2\omega = -\arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Since $\omega \in [0, 2\pi]$, we require that $2\omega \in [0, 4\pi] \implies m \in \{0, 1\}$, which yields the solutions 
\begin{align*}
2\omega & = \arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) & 2\omega & = \arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 2\pi\\
\omega & = \frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) & \omega & = \frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + \pi\\
\end{align*}
and $n \in \{1, 2\}$, which yields the solutions
\begin{align*}
2\omega & = -\arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 2\pi & 2\omega & = -\arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 4\pi\\
\omega & = -\frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + \pi & \omega & = -\frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 2\pi
\end{align*}

Similarly, $\cos 2\omega = \dfrac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4} \implies$
$$2\omega = \arccos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$2\omega = -\arccos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Since $\omega in [0, 2\pi] \implies 2\omega \in [0, 4\pi]$, $m \in \{0, 1\}$, which yields the solutions 
\begin{align*}
2\omega & = \arccos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) & 2\omega & = \arccos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 2\pi\\
\omega & = \frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) & \omega & = \frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + \pi\\
\end{align*}
and $n \in \{1, 2\}$, which yields the solutions
\begin{align*}
2\omega & = -\arccos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 2\pi & 2\omega & = -\arccos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 4\pi\\
\omega & = -\frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + \pi & \omega & = -\frac{1}{2}\arccos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 2\pi
\end{align*}

**An alternate solution:**

Consider the following diagram.

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

Two directed angles in standard position (vertex at the origin, initial side on the positive $x$-axis) have the same sine if the $y$-coordinates of the points where the terminal sides of the angles intersect the unit circle are equal.  By symmetry, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ if $\varphi = \theta$ or $\varphi = \pi - \theta$.  Since any angle coterminal with these angles has the same $y$-coordinate, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ if 
$$\varphi = \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = \pi - \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Let's return to the original problem.
\begin{align*}
\sin 4\omega - \sin 6\omega & = 0\\
\sin 4\omega & = \sin 6\omega
\end{align*}

Setting $\theta = 4\omega$ and $\varphi = 6\omega$ yields 
\begin{align*}
6\omega & = 4\omega + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z} & 6\omega & = \pi - 4\omega + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
2\omega & = 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z} & 10\omega & = \pi + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\omega & = m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z} & \omega & = \frac{\pi}{10} + \frac{n\pi}{5}, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
Restricting our attention to the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ implies $m \in \{0, 1, 2\}$, which yields the solutions 
$$\omega = 0, \pi, 2\pi$$
and $n \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$, which yields the solutions
$$\omega = \frac{\pi}{10}, \frac{3\pi}{10}, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{7\pi}{10}, \frac{9\pi}{10}, \frac{11\pi}{10}, \frac{13\pi}{10}, \frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{17\pi}{10}, \frac{19\pi}{10}$$ 
as you can verify by direct substitution and the use of symmetry.

Notice that with this method, you do not need to know that 
$$\arccos\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) = \frac{\pi}{5}$$
or that 
$$\arccos\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) = \frac{3\pi}{5}$$

Comment: Taussig Very much thanks for that elegant description of my problem. Initially I was a bit confused on why did the interval $[0, 2 \pi]$ became enlarged. But by following your explanation it made sense that it was due the angle was $\textrm{n times}$, therefore the upper boundary would be affected by this condition. Then I thought, what if such angle would had been offset by some other angle, let's say $\left( \omega + \phi \right)$ being $\phi$ the offset. Then I realized that such procedure would be the same, just the upper boundary would be summed that offset.

Comment: But since sine or cosine functions are periodical a little addition of let's say $\frac{\pi}{4}$ wouldn't make any difference if what it is being asked is $1$ for example. From then on, I'm really appreciate the fact that you made clear about what is happening with the square root, I missed the two solutions and just considered one. I'll take these consideration in further exercises.

Comment: Btw, what software did you used to draw the unit circle?. The second method seemed more straightforward of what I used and probably will end up using it in similar problems, as mentioned to other user my initial doubts where If prosthaphaeresis would apply in this case and it does, and as long I use it properly I will not lose any solutions. As mentioned I hope to be understanding it well.

Comment: You are welcome.  I am glad you found my solution helpful.  I drew the diagram using the [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) drawing program [TikZ](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PGF/TikZ).  Here is a [manual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(4\omega)-\sin(6\omega)
&=\sin(5\omega-\omega)-\sin(5\omega+\omega)\\
&=-2\cos(5\omega)\sin(\omega)
\end{align}
$$
so we need either
$$
\cos(5\omega)=0\iff5\omega=\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi
$$
or
$$
\sin(\omega)=0\iff\omega=k\pi
$$
Therefore, we get the solutions
$$
\omega\in\left\{\frac{2k+1}{10}\pi,k\pi:k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$

Comment: Interesting avatar you have there. Okay, back to the problem. Yes this is what I tried to do initially but I wasn't sure if it would apply, but as others mentioned all safe to go. Just I have to make sure I get all the solutions within the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.

Comment: There are $13$ solutions listed above in $[0,2\pi]$: $\left\{0,\frac\pi{10},\frac{3\pi}{10},\frac\pi2,\frac{7\pi}{10},\frac{9\pi}{10},\pi,\frac{11\pi}{10},\frac{13\pi}{10},\frac{3\pi}2,\frac{17\pi}{10},\frac{19\pi}{10},2\pi\right\}$

Comment: Thanks about that I noticed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have this general theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $A,B$ be real numbers. Then
>   $$AB = 0 \quad \iff \quad (A=0) \lor (B=0) $$

In plain words, it is necessary and sufficient that either $A = 0$ *or* $B = 0$ (or both) for $AB$ to also equal $0$. This means that your problem is logically equivalent to determining under which conditions $A = 0$ and under which (generally different) conditions $B  =0$, and then taking the *union* of those conditions. Why the union? Let's say that $A$ and $B$ depend on $\omega$: only some of the $\omega$'s are such that $A(\omega) = 0$, and similarly only some of the $\omega$'s are such that $B(\omega) = 0$, and there may even be some $\omega$'s for which both $A(\omega) = B(\omega) = 0$. We want to take *all* of these $\omega$'s (we wouldn't want to leave any solutions behind), so that's why we take the union.

In your specific case, $A(\omega) = \cos(5\omega)$ and $B(\omega) = \sin\omega$, so that
  $$5\omega = \arccos0=\frac \pi 2 + k\pi,\quad  \forall k \in \mathbb Z, \qquad \omega = \arcsin 0 = k\pi,\quad \forall k \in \mathbb Z $$
are the two conditions you're looking for. Ultimately, your equation is satisfied whenever $\omega = k \pi$ or $\omega = \frac \pi 5\left(\frac 1 2 + k\right)$, for some $k \in \mathbb Z$, that is, it is necessary and sufficient for $\omega$ to take either one of these forms for $\omega$ to be an acceptable solution to your equation. This means you have found all possible solutions to the original equation.

---

A side note: at some point in your calculations, you were to calculate
$$\arccos\left(\frac{1 + 2\sqrt 5}{4}\right) $$
but this is nonsensical, because the argument of $\arccos$ is a real number greater than $1$, and we know that the range of the cosine function is $[-1,1]$. You just have to ditch this case. If you switch the $+$ with a $-$, however, you do get a number lying in the range of the cosine, so it's all fine there – even though, if you plug it in your original equation, you do not get zero, so somewhere in your calculations you must have made a mistake...

Comment: Thanks for that short summary about properties of real numbers. As I mentioned in the comments my biggest fear was on how to avoid leaving out any solutions. But as long I consider the individual results as a union then all will be okay. It is not written in the problem specifically but generally I'm requested to select the values within the interval $[0, 2 \pi]$. From this I obtained the same results as yours.

Comment: As you mentioned I forgot to consider about the boundaries of the cosine function, that case and the other (switching the sign). However the question was regarding on whether if my calculations were correct. Can you help me to spot the error?. Because I have repeated the algebraic process and all seems correct.

Comment: I spotted the error, it was on the discriminant where should had been $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Now all seems to check with the result and the interval where it lies the cosine function. But these values are not shown in the method which uses the prosthaphaeresis. Why could that be?. Btw I've checked with the original equation and it checks with the value of zero.

Comment: Are you sure they don't show up using prosthaphaeresis?
$$\frac \pi 5 \left( \frac 1 2 + 1\right) = \frac 1 2 \arccos \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{4} \right) .$$

Comment: For the other solutions, try out the values $k=0, k=8, k=9$.

Comment: I totally overlooked that part. Is it an identity or just simple observation? Because other than just comparing both numerically I don't know how to check these $\frac{\pi}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)= \frac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}\left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)$. I'm surprised how they are shown in different ways. Is there one way more "fancy" or "orthodox" than the other or?. As you mentioned the remaining check with the values of $0,\,8,\,9$. My method seems more complicated than just going in the initial route, not to mention the necessity of solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: If you set $$\theta_k := \frac \pi 5 \left( \frac 1 2 + k \right),$$
and draw the points $(\cos\theta_k,\sin\theta_k)$ in the plane, you see that they lie on the unit circle and make out the vertices of a *regular decagon* (a polygon with ten sides of equal length). Then you may proceed by synthetic geometry: for example, $\cos\theta_0$ is the *apothem* of the polygon, and there is a well-known formula for that...

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way: use the relation

$$\sin m \omega = \sin n \omega \implies n \omega = m \omega + 2 \pi k \text { or }  n \omega = \pi - m \omega + 2 \pi k$$

If $m = 4$ and $n = 6$, you should have as solutions

$$\omega = (k - 1)\pi \vee \omega = \dfrac {(2k - 1) \pi}{10}, k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$